# change parent props from child component in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to change the parent's prop's value from a child component. This works great in vuejs 1 but not in vue 2 (I want to use it in vue.js 2).

Here is a small example :

## HTML

```
<div id="app">
   <parent :content="{value:'hello parent'}"><</parent>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
var parent = {
  template: '<child :content="content"></child>',
  props: ['content'],
};

var child = {
  template: '<div>{{ content.value }}<button @click="change">change me</button></div>',
  props: ['content'],
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.content.value = "Value changed !";
    }
  }
};

Vue.component('child', child);
Vue.component('parent', parent);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f5gt94f2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tl;dr: in vue2, you need to use the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier).

Create a local copy of the `content` prop in the parent's `data` ([see reason here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3836#issuecomment-251232850)).

```
var parent = {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      localContent: this.content // creating a local copy, so we can mutate and react to it
    }
  }
};
```

Now, pass that `localContent` to the child, not `content`. And [pass it using `.sync` so it can be updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier):

```
var parent = {
  template: '<div><child :content.sync="localContent"></child></div>',
  ...                     //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- changed here
```

Now, in the child, don't assign to `this.content.value`, emit an update event instead:

```
var child = {
    ...
    change() {
      this.$emit('update:content', {value: "Value changed !"})
    }
  }
};
```

This event, with the new value, will be picked up by the parent and will update its `localContent` which also will, in consequence, update the child's `content` prop.

Final running code below.

```js
var parent = {
  template: '<div><child :content.sync="localContent"></child><br>At parent: {{ localContent }}</div>',
  props: ['content'],
  data() {
    return {
      localContent: this.content
    }
  }
};

var child = {
  template: '<div>At child: {{ content.value }}<button @click="change">change me</button></div>',
  props: ['content'],
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.$emit('update:content', {value: "Value changed !"})
    }
  }
};

Vue.component('child', child);
Vue.component('parent', parent);

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent :content="{value:'hello parent'}"></parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent ! I didn't know that .sync is back again, I also can use `this.content.value = "helloooo";` instead of `this.$emit('update:content', {value: "Value changed !"})` and it works

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't, it is sort of a bad practice. And it only works because `value` is a nested property, and because it is reactive (due to being a `data` property in the parent). The `content` that arrives at the `parent` is not reactive, for example, because it was passed via a literal `<parent :content="{value:'hello parent'}">`. But, anyway, if you are aware of the drawbacks, but think changing directly is worth it (I can understand that), then you can use it, or course.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use emit events for this

**Parent:**

```
<child :content="content" @updateParent="updateValue"></child>

methods: {
  updateValue (value) {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

---

**Child:**

```
props: ['content'],
methods: {
  change () {
    this.$emit('updateParent', value)
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events